# Is there a reason why we add (CH3CSNH2) but not H2S in qualitative group analysis?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, analytical-chemistry

> Brief question: In $\ce{Cu}$-$\ce{As}$ group analysis we are expected to add thinoacetamide to make a precipitate with sulfide. Can we use $\ce{H2S}$ instead?

[image: Cu-As Group]

Comment: For safety reasons. Older generations of chemists who studied in 70s-90s will remember the stench of rotten eggs of the gas.

Comment: Please do not insert vertical pictures, which are hard to read. Put them in horizontal position.

Comment: Go and look up how toxic H2S is.

Comment: @M.Farooq Unfortunately hydrolysis of thioacetamide also stinks :(

Comment: @Mithoron, Still better than using Kipp's apparatus. Have you ever used one?

Comment: @Mithoron, So you don't belong to that club when qualitative inorganic analysis had all this stuff. Mercury is a no-no, so is Kipp's apparatus.

Comment: In my qualitative inorganic course they were called $\ce{H2S}$ group. It was also said that ‘use TAA but we do have a gas bottle in case you have a really pesky analysis.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne And thanks for editing, sorry I didn't know how to..